# Python: Numpy array to List of lists through condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of cell coordinates where the frist three elements are the coordinates, the 4th element is the time step and the 5th element is the Cell ID. I would like to convert it to a lists of lists, where every list stands for antother cell. Adttionaly i want the same for a numpy array of numpy arrays. So the list/array should be split whenever the 5th element (CellID) is another. So so 5th element has numbers from 1000000000.0 to 1000000297.0 but after that it starts over from 1000000000.0 to 1000000166.0. The problem is that these are different cells and should not merged together. I suggest that to work with masks would be the most efficient way but I dont know how.

**Example:**

**Input:**

```
[[  2.43130000e+01   2.94679000e+02   1.50000000e+00   1.00000000e+00
1.00000000e+09]
[  2.55100000e+01   2.95263000e+02   1.50000000e+00   2.00000000e+00
    1.00000000e+09]
 [  2.67430000e+01   2.94526000e+02   1.50000000e+00   3.00000000e+00
    1.00000000e+09]
 ..., 
 [  2.82311000e+02   5.35420000e+01   1.50000000e+00   1.00000000e+02
    1.00000017e+09]
 [  2.86946000e+02   5.49790000e+01   9.17700000e+00   1.01000000e+02
    1.00000017e+09]
 [  2.93990000e+02   5.19340000e+01   1.29780000e+01   1.02000000e+02
    1.00000017e+09]]
```

**Extract for Output for List of Lists**

```
[[[130.463, 248.155, 55.5, 96.0, 1000000161.0], [132.628, 252.684, 52.356, 97.0, 1000000161.0], [137.9, 255.265, 46.883, 98.0, 1000000161.0], [132.053, 258.447, 45.077, 99.0, 1000000161.0], [134.003, 259.702, 44.496, 100.0, 1000000161.0], [135.481, 257.842, 39.964, 101.0, 1000000161.0], [140.443, 256.546, 33.973, 102.0, 1000000161.0], [219.541, 192.737, 1.5, 98.0, 1000000162.0], [[213.184, 188.749, 1.5, 99.0, 1000000162.0], [211.233, 183.231, 1.5, 100.0, 1000000162.0], [205.015, 180.092, 1.5, 101.0, 1000000162.0], [201.842, 177.759, 1.5, 102.0, 1000000162.0], [197.246, 175.923, 1.5, 103.0, 1000000162.0]], [[238.615, 95.605, 29.725, 98.0, 1000000163.0], [229.771, 90.084, 26.762, 99.0, 1000000163.0], [226.749, 82.741, 19.857, 100.0, 1000000163.0], [228.741, 78.017, 15.398, 101.0, 1000000163.0], [227.645, 75.927, 9.396, 102.0, 1000000163.0], [226.383, 66.733, 1.5, 103.0, 1000000163.0]], [[267.344, 47.023, 19.123, 98.0, 1000000164.0], [267.265, 43.635, 19.669, 99.0, 1000000164.0], [271.186, 47.123, 10.944, 100.0, 1000000164.0], [275.205, 45.156, 10.225, 101.0, 1000000164.0], [281.018, 48.663, 7.118, 102.0, 1000000164.0]], [[257.359, 225.509, 1.5, 103.0, 1000000165.0]], [[281.395, 58.163, 1.5, 98.0, 1000000166.0], [282.415, 55.211, 1.5, 99.0, 1000000166.0], [282.311, 53.542, 1.5, 100.0, 1000000166.0], [286.946, 54.979, 9.177, 101.0, 1000000166.0], [293.99, 51.934, 12.978, 102.0, 1000000166.0]]]
```

**But tuples are also ok:**

```
[[(130.463, 248.155, 55.5, 96.0, 1000000161.0), (132.628, 252.684, 52.356, 97.0, 1000000161.0), (137.9, 255.265, 46.883, 98.0, 1000000161.0), (132.053, 258.447, 45.077, 99.0, 1000000161.0), (134.003, 259.702, 44.496, 100.0, 1000000161.0), (135.481, 257.842, 39.964, 101.0, 1000000161.0), (140.443, 256.546, 33.973, 102.0, 1000000161.0), (219.541, 192.737, 1.5, 98.0, 1000000162.0), [(213.184, 188.749, 1.5, 99.0, 1000000162.0), (211.233, 183.231, 1.5, 100.0, 1000000162.0), (205.015, 180.092, 1.5, 101.0, 1000000162.0), (201.842, 177.759, 1.5, 102.0, 1000000162.0), (197.246, 175.923, 1.5, 103.0, 1000000162.0)], [(238.615, 95.605, 29.725, 98.0, 1000000163.0), (229.771, 90.084, 26.762, 99.0, 1000000163.0), (226.749, 82.741, 19.857, 100.0, 1000000163.0), (228.741, 78.017, 15.398, 101.0, 1000000163.0), ....]]
```

Comment: A proper example with input and expected result would go a long way to clear up that confusing specs followed by an uncommented dump of a 2D list.

Comment: @timgeb I edited it. I hope it is more clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

If the arrays with the time steps for one cell are consecutive, I believe this should work:

```
list_of_lists = []
temporary_list = []

# store the current cellID:
cellID = list[0][-1]
for element in list:
    if element[-1]==cellID:
        temporary_list.append(element)
    else:
        list_of_lists.append(temporary_list)
        temporary_list = []
        cellID = element[-1]
# append the last temporary_list:
list_of_lists.append(temporary_list)
```